# Why does shifting an array within an array affect copied (not by reference) arrays, but shifting the whole initial array does not? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am trying to shift an array and use that array, then set it to its original values using a copied array that was copied not by reference. For some reason, shifting arrays from the original array does not affect the copied array, but shifting elements from within arrays in the initial array does affect the copied array. How do I copy an array, modify it, use it, then set it back to its original form?

I originally was having trouble because I was copying by reference, but then I learned that using the rest operator allowed me to copy the array (not by reference). It seems the two datum are still linked.

```
var m = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
var matrix = [...m]
m.shift();
console.log(matrix);
m[0].shift();
console.log(m);
console.log(matrix);
```

Expected:

```
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]
[ [ 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]
```

Actual:

```
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]
[ [ 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 7, 8, 9 ] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the second degree arrays are still being passed by reference when you do `[...m]`. I'm not sure how you could still use the rest operator but another thing you could do is:

```
var matrix = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(m));
```

to avoid the problem.

```js
var m = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

var matrix = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(m));

m.shift();
console.log(matrix);
m[0].shift();
console.log(m);
console.log(matrix);
```

Comment: Using this method, can I set m = matrix (after shifting m) to make m its original form?

Comment: Yes, that would be the case. Though bear in mind that will make the m variable point to a new array object. This may or may not be a problem (it would be a problem, for example, if m was a "const").